# Make a Select All Button in ListBox

Tags: excel, vba

I have a listBox in excel how you can see below:

[image: List Box]

How can i implement the checkbox for select All ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a code like below to achieve this.

```
'\\ Change ListBox1 to actual ListBox name in your code
Dim i as Long
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    '\\ Use False in case if you need to unselect all!
    ListBox1.Selected(i) = True
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks, it's Run  Fine !

Comment: Do you know if exist a Third Value for a checkbox in VBA ? for example, in some forms of another lenguages the checkbox have a partial value that can be represented with a filled square on center.

Comment: @LeonardoSoaresBezerra I am not aware and I have not used. Possibly it would be `Checkbox1.Value = Null`.

Comment: it`s doesn`t work , but i will try another way. Thanks.